# Windows console synchronized settings between PCs and high-dpi

Tags: windows-8, console, onedrive

Starting Windows 8.1, console settings are stored in the microsoft profile associated with the account and [synchronized between all PCs](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/sync-settings-pcs).

In my case, I own different devices with different DPI settings : on my notebook, I use a 200% scale, so my console font will be 24pt or more, and on my regular desktop pc, I still use the default font size.

I store my settings using the "default" settings screen from the console title bar.

But because my settings are synchronized on each devices, each time I change device, my settings are overwritten.

I know that I can [disable application settings synchronization globally](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/sync-settings-pcs), but I still want this feature enabled for other settings.

**So my question is : can we disable settings synchronization/storage between devices for a specific app ?**

I have already looked into registry, there are keys under `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SettingSync\Namespace\Windows\CommandPrompt` but they only set the last time settings were changed, I suppose to detect if new settings must be applied/saved.

Comment: One of the toggles [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2MpYm.jpg) has to be responsible, perhaps "Other Windows settings". I don't think it's possible to get any more fine-grained than that and not sync just the console related settings.

Comment: you are right, but I am still interested in synchronizing other settings.

Comment: it seems I have found a wat to disable synchronization with the registry key `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SettingSync\SyncData\ReportNamespace\windows\commandprompt` by setting the key `RemoteInterest` to 0. I will post the solution if tests are positive.

Comment: Sounds interesting; let us know the results.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it seems I have found a solution by myself.

In the registry, there are keys under `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SettingSync\SyncData\ReportNames‌​pace` with values named `RemoteInterest` set to 1.

It appears that if you set this setting to 0, the SyncSetting service will not try to apply remote settings anymore.

So, I have just set this value to 0 in the `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SettingSync\SyncData\ReportNames‌​pace\windows\commandprompt` key on my both PCs, and now the font-size seems to be no more overwritten.